# Resubmission of paper has been "under consideration" for 30 days. Request update?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, editors

I (re)submitted my paper to a Nature related journal (after revisions) and it has been "under consideration" for about 30 days. Should I ask for an update? If yes, is this too rude?  :

---

Dear editor,

I hope you are doing well. I have noticed that the status of our paper titled “ “ has not changed for about 30 days. I am not sure what the time frame is for resubmissions. Is it possible I have missed an update? If there is anything I need to do at this stage, please let me know.

---

Comment: What did happen in the end?

Answer (score 6):

Journals such as nature and Science and their related publications run on tight schedules. Not hearing from them quickly is usually a good thing since rejections are made quickly. Yes, a month may seem long but for me is too early to worry. It is difficult to say what time frame is reasonable but two months would be on the long side.

Having said that, these journals have professionals working full time with the journal, unlike many others where editors work on the journal along side regular academic work. This means they rarely let any job lie around for very long. Of course, a mistake may happen, but I would not make such an assumption as a first choice. So take it easy for another couple of weeks. If there is any pressure on you for getting advance notice of publication, for, for example, job applications or salary discussions, a mail providing the cause of urgency would always be possible but if it is only pressing anticipation, sending mails to editors early is not a great idea. But in this case, estimating the time frame is more difficult than for regular journals but give it another couple fo weeks at least.